# Neo4j GraphSage training does not log anything

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphsage

I am working on extracting graph embeddings with training GraphSage algorihm. I am working on a large graph consisting of (82,339,589) nodes and (219,521,164) edges. When I checked with ":queries" command the query is listed as running. Algorithm started in 6 days ago. When I look the logs with "docker logs xxx" the last logs listed as

> 2021-12-01 12:03:16.267+0000 INFO Relationship Store Scan (RelationshipScanCursorBasedScanner): Imported 352,492,468 records and 0 properties from 16247 MiB (17,036,668,320 bytes); took 59.057 s, 5,968,663.57 Relationships/s, 275 MiB/s (288,477,487 bytes/s) (per thread: 1,492,165.89 Relationships/s, 68 MiB/s (72,119,371 bytes/s))

> 2021-12-01 12:03:16.269+0000 INFO [neo4j.BoltWorker-3 [bolt] [/10.0.0.6:56143] ] LOADING
>
> INFO  [neo4j.BoltWorker-3 [bolt] [/10.0.0.6:56143] ] LOADING Actual
> memory usage of the loaded graph: 8602 MiB
>
> INFO [neo4j.BoltWorker-3 [bolt] [/10.0.0.6:64076] ] GraphSageTrain ::
> Start

There is a way to see detailed logs about training process. Is it normal for taking 6 days for graphs with shared sizes ?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal for GraphSAGE to take a long time compared to FastRP or Node2Vec. Starting in GDS 1.7, you can use

```
CALL gds.beta.listProgress(jobId: String)
YIELD
  jobId,
  taskName,
  progress,
  progressBar,
  status,
  timeStarted,
  elapsedTime
```

If you call without passing in a jobId, it will return a list of all running jobs. If you call with a jobId, it will give you details about a running job.

This query will summarize the details for job `03d90ed8-feba-4959-8cd2-cbd691d1da6c`.

```
CALL gds.beta.listProgress("03d90ed8-feba-4959-8cd2-cbd691d1da6c") 
YIELD taskName, status 
RETURN taskName, status, count(*)
```

Here's the [documentation for progress logging](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/1.8/common-usage/logging/). The [system monitoring](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/1.8/common-usage/monitoring-system/) procedures might also be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I use GDS version 1.6.5. However I read 1.6.5 version is not be updated. I will switch to 1.7 version for checking progress.